# How can I see output of .class file in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have developed code in eclipse and copy only .class file to tomcat's `WEB-INF/Class/PackageName/` folder and run the code from browser after proper set up in web.xml.

Now I want to see the output of executed file that I can see in eclipse. how can I see the output of .class file after execution?

Comment: Do you mean things written to `System.out`?

Comment: I tried with System.out, It shows output in eclipse but not in browser.

Comment: That path is certainly wrong

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Comment: This is not how a [Servlet container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) should be used...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this using the startup.sh/bat script, it should log all your `System.out` output to `logs/catalina.out`.

Comment: OP wants to get it _in the browser_.

Comment: I want to see only output, It doesn't matter where.